# FlappyBird on Pygame. How can I change speed of pipe with buttons?

Tags: python, pygame

```
# Import module
import random
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# All the Game Variables
window_width = 600
window_height = 499

# set height and width of window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
elevation = window_height * 0.8
game_images = {}
framepersecond = 32
pipeimage = 'images/pipe.png'
background_image = 'images/background.jpg'
birdplayer_image = 'images/bird.png'
sealevel_image = 'images/base.jfif'


def flappygame():
   your_score = 0
   horizontal = int(window_width/5)
   vertical = int(window_width/2)
   ground = 0
   mytempheight = 100

   # Generating two pipes for blitting on window
   first_pipe = createPipe()
   second_pipe = createPipe()

   # List containing lower pipes
   down_pipes = [
      {'x': window_width+300-mytempheight,
      'y': first_pipe[1]['y']},
      {'x': window_width+300-mytempheight+(window_width/2),
      'y': second_pipe[1]['y']},
   ]

   # List Containing upper pipes
   up_pipes = [
      {'x': window_width+300-mytempheight,
      'y': first_pipe[0]['y']},
      {'x': window_width+200-mytempheight+(window_width/2),
      'y': second_pipe[0]['y']},
   ]

   # pipe velocity along x
   pipeVelX = -4 #It's default speed of pipe


   # bird velocity
   bird_velocity_y = -9
   bird_Max_Vel_Y = 10
   bird_Min_Vel_Y = -8
   birdAccY = 1
   bird_velocity_x = 0

   bird_flap_velocity = -8
   bird_flapped = False
   while True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
            if vertical > 0:
               bird_velocity_y = bird_flap_velocity
               bird_flapped = True
         
         # I added this part for change speed, but the game crashes
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_1):
            pipeVelX = -4
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_2):
            pipeVelX = -8
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_3):
            pipeVelX = -12



      # This function will return true
      # if the flappybird is crashed
      game_over = isGameOver(horizontal,
                     vertical,
                     up_pipes,
                     down_pipes)
      if game_over:
         return

      # check for your_score
      playerMidPos = horizontal + game_images['flappybird'].get_width()/2
      for pipe in up_pipes:
         pipeMidPos = pipe['x'] + game_images['pipeimage'][0].get_width()/2
         if pipeMidPos <= playerMidPos < pipeMidPos + 4:
            your_score += 1
            print(f"Your your_score is {your_score}")

      if bird_velocity_y < bird_Max_Vel_Y and not bird_flapped:
         bird_velocity_y += birdAccY

      if bird_flapped:
         bird_flapped = False
      playerHeight = game_images['flappybird'].get_height()
      vertical = vertical + \
         min(bird_velocity_y, elevation - vertical - playerHeight)

      # move pipes to the left
      for upperPipe, lowerPipe in zip(up_pipes, down_pipes):
         upperPipe['x'] += pipeVelX
         lowerPipe['x'] += pipeVelX

      # Add a new pipe when the first is
      # about to cross the leftmost part of the screen
      if 0 < up_pipes[0]['x'] < 5:
         newpipe = createPipe()
         up_pipes.append(newpipe[0])
         down_pipes.append(newpipe[1])

      # if the pipe is out of the screen, remove it
      if up_pipes[0]['x'] < -game_images['pipeimage'][0].get_width():
         up_pipes.pop(0)
         down_pipes.pop(0)

      # Lets blit our game images now
      window.blit(game_images['background'], (0, 0))
      for upperPipe, lowerPipe in zip(up_pipes, down_pipes):
         window.blit(game_images['pipeimage'][0],
                  (upperPipe['x'], upperPipe['y']))
         window.blit(game_images['pipeimage'][1],
                  (lowerPipe['x'], lowerPipe['y']))

      window.blit(game_images['sea_level'], (ground, elevation))
      window.blit(game_images['flappybird'], (horizontal, vertical))

      # Fetching the digits of score.
      numbers = [int(x) for x in list(str(your_score))]
      width = 0

      # finding the width of score images from numbers.
      for num in numbers:
         width += game_images['scoreimages'][num].get_width()
      Xoffset = (window_width - width)/1.1

      # Blitting the images on the window.
      for num in numbers:
         window.blit(game_images['scoreimages'][num],
                  (Xoffset, window_width*0.02))
         Xoffset += game_images['scoreimages'][num].get_width()

      # Refreshing the game window and displaying the score.
      pygame.display.update()
      framepersecond_clock.tick(framepersecond)


def isGameOver(horizontal, vertical, up_pipes, down_pipes):
   if vertical > elevation - 25 or vertical < 0:
      return True

   for pipe in up_pipes:
      pipeHeight = game_images['pipeimage'][0].get_height()
      if(vertical < pipeHeight + pipe['y'] and\
      abs(horizontal - pipe['x']) < game_images['pipeimage'][0].get_width()):
         return True

   for pipe in down_pipes:
      if (vertical + game_images['flappybird'].get_height() > pipe['y']) and\
      abs(horizontal - pipe['x']) < game_images['pipeimage'][0].get_width():
         return True
   return False


def createPipe():
   offset = window_height/3
   pipeHeight = game_images['pipeimage'][0].get_height()
   y2 = offset + \
      random.randrange(
         0, int(window_height - game_images['sea_level'].get_height() - 1.2 * offset))
   pipeX = window_width + 10
   y1 = pipeHeight - y2 + offset
   pipe = [
      # upper Pipe
      {'x': pipeX, 'y': -y1},

      # lower Pipe
      {'x': pipeX, 'y': y2}
   ]
   return pipe


# program where the game starts
if __name__ == "__main__":

      # For initializing modules of pygame library
   pygame.init()
   framepersecond_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

   # Sets the title on top of game window
   pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Bird Game')

   # Load all the images which we will use in the game

   # images for displaying score
   game_images['scoreimages'] = (
      pygame.image.load('images/0.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/1.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/2.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/3.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/4.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/5.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/6.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/7.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/8.png').convert_alpha(),
      pygame.image.load('images/9.png').convert_alpha()
   )
   game_images['flappybird'] = pygame.image.load(
      birdplayer_image).convert_alpha()
   game_images['sea_level'] = pygame.image.load(
      sealevel_image).convert_alpha()
   game_images['background'] = pygame.image.load(
      background_image).convert_alpha()
   game_images['pipeimage'] = (pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.image.load(
      pipeimage).convert_alpha(), 180), pygame.image.load(
   pipeimage).convert_alpha())

   print("WELCOME TO THE FLAPPY BIRD GAME")
   print("Press space or enter to start the game")

   # Here starts the main game

   while True:

      # sets the coordinates of flappy bird

      horizontal = int(window_width/5)
      vertical = int(
         (window_height - game_images['flappybird'].get_height())/2)
      ground = 0
      while True:
         for event in pygame.event.get():

            # if user clicks on cross button, close the game
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and \
                              event.key == K_ESCAPE):
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()

            # If the user presses space or
            # up key, start the game for them
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or\
                                    event.key == K_UP):
               flappygame()

            # if user doesn't press anykey Nothing happen
            else:
               window.blit(game_images['background'], (0, 0))
               window.blit(game_images['flappybird'],
                        (horizontal, vertical))
               window.blit(game_images['sea_level'], (ground, elevation))
               pygame.display.update()
               framepersecond_clock.tick(framepersecond)
```

I can't understand why it crashes, I roughly did the above, that is, if I pressed 1, then the speed was normal, if 2, then 2 times faster, 3 - three times faster, but when I change the speed it crashes, can you help how you can change the speed of the pipe by the buttons

pipeVelX = -4 #It's default speed of pipe

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_SPACE or event.key == K_UP):
            if vertical > 0:
               bird_velocity_y = bird_flap_velocity
               bird_flapped = True
         
         # I added this part for change speed, but the game crashes
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_1):
            pipeVelX = -4
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_2):
            pipeVelX = -8
         if event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key == K_3):
            pipeVelX = -12
```

Comment: *"but when I change the speed it crashes, "* - How does it crash? What is the exception/error message?

Comment: not errors, nothing. Just It's like I'm out of the game

Answer (score 0):

You remove the pipes when the x coordinate is in a certain range on the left side of the screen:

> ```py
> if 0 < up_pipes[0]['x'] < 5:
> ```

When the velocity increases, the x coordinate of the pipes may never be in this range. It is absolutely not necessary to test for an range. Simply remove the pipes when they are off the screen:

```py
if up_pipes[0]['x'] <= 0:
```

Or course it is also possible to increase the range with the velocity:

```py
if 0 < up_pipes[0]['x'] <= pipeVelX:
```

Comment: @damir Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)